# Get schema(user) name from database

Tags: sql, database, oracle10g

How to find the schema(user) name from database using a select statement or are there any built in functions available?

I am using the following package for compiling all invalid objects in my schema, so instead of hard coding schema name, I would like to use a select statement or function which returns schema name.

```
DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema('SCOTT');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, the [`USER`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e10540/variables.htm#r2c1-t4) system variable would correspond to what you need, if "my schema" corresponds to "my user", [what it usually does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880230/difference-between-a-user-and-a-schema-in-oracle):

```
declare
  u varchar2(100);
begin
  select user into u from dual;
  DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(u);
end;
```

Or without a PL/SQL block

```
DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(user);
```

Comment: No need for a PL/SQL block: `DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(user);` should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

Schemas in Oracle DB are users, so if you want to take all schemas you need to use the dba_users table:

```
SELECT USERNAME
FROM DBA_USERS;
```

Remember that this is a system table so appropriate user granting is necessary.

If you need the current user, you can user the USER_USERS view. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4174.htm) for further information.

Hope this helps!