# what is syntax for writing a private synonym in oracle 10G?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am using following syntax for creating a private synonym of a table in oracle 10G:

```
create private synonym <synonym name>
for <schema name>.<table name>;
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Please guide me with correct syntax . I did research however i found syntax for public synonym only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me:

```
create or replace synonym SCHEMA1.TABLE for SCHEMA2.TABLE;
```

or for your schema

```
create or replace synonym TABLE for SCHEMA2.TABLE;
```

where `SCHEMA1.TABLE` or `TABLE` are synonym name.

[Here](http://psoug.org/reference/synonyms.html) there is a lot of examples.

Comment: where the word SCHEMA has the oracle notation of schema (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880230/difference-between-a-user-and-a-schema-in-oracle)... and it does not stand for "tablespace"

Answer (score 5):

Just omit the `private` keyword.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm):

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] [ PUBLIC ] SYNONYM
   [ schema. ]synonym 
   FOR [ schema. ]object [ @ dblink ] ;
```

> **PUBLIC**
>   If you omit this clause, then the synonym is private and is accessible only within its schema. A private synonym name must be unique in its schema.