# Schema and Owner of Table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, schema

Is the schema for a table and the owner for a table the same in oracle? If not what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Tom says](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11%5FQUESTION%5FID:6162110256950):

> You should consider a schema to be the user account and collection of
>   all objects therein  as a schema for all intents and purposes.

A table created by a user - and therefore owned by that user, as the `owner` in `all_tables` for example - forms part of that user's schema. So yes, the owner and schema are the same.

Also see [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/880230/266304), which references the same AskTom post, and also highlights this line from it:

> for all intents and purposes just consider user = schema = user =
>   schema =  the same thing

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, schema and owner of a table are technically identical.

If you talk about a **schema** you usually refer to all objects owned by a user, but when you say **user** it often means only someone who can connect to the database. But this is just language use - again, technically **user** is the same as **schema**.

People coming from other databases will often equate **schema** with **database**, since often all the tables are in one schema. This can make matters a bit muddled when talking about Oracle with SQL-Server people, for example.