# Transition of SQL Server's Login/User concept to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, security, access-control

in SQL Server users are first registered on the server level as **Logins**, and after that they are added to all necessary databases on that server as **Users**.

Is there something comparable in Oracle? I understand that the Oracle object Tablespace kind of represents the database object in SQL Server, but nevertheless it appears to me as if in Oracle solely database users are registered which gain access to database objects via fine-granular GRANT/DENY operations and role memberships.

Thanks in advance,
Jan

Comment: You can "grant [select or update or insert or ...] on any table" to a user - this is on a database level. So there are several grants per user.  This is not secure from an oracle perspective. You can also create a single role that has those properties then give that role to any user.  It is not as fine-grained as you perceive.

Answer (score 0):

Check this post:

[Difference between a user and a schema in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880230/difference-between-a-user-and-a-schema-in-oracle/11764849#11764849)

I (too) started with Sql Server and had to learn the different phrasing for Oracle.