# How to create new schema and list all schema name in oracle

Tags: oracle, schema, authorization, database-schema

I want to create one new schema in oracle and I used sample code, which is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6014.htm)

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION oe
   CREATE TABLE new_product
      (color VARCHAR2(10)  PRIMARY KEY, quantity NUMBER)
   CREATE VIEW new_product_view
      AS SELECT color, quantity FROM new_product WHERE color = 'RED'
   GRANT select ON new_product_view TO scott
/
```

But, getting error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02421: missing or invalid schema authorization identifier
```

Also, Please help me how to list name of all available schema. I am using

```
 select username from dba_users;
```

to list schema, but i think, its not a right approach, because, user and schema has many-to-many relation,which means I can't get all schema name here.

Please help me !!

Comment: In oracle user and schema *don't* have many-to-many relation (actually the difference is more semantic - they are quite the same)

Comment: Why ? one user can have multiple schema and a schema can be associated with multiple users. Isn't ?

Comment: In oracle `user` and `schema` are pretty much the same. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880230/difference-between-a-user-and-a-schema-in-oracle)

Comment: but, it says "roughly equivalent to a user account"

Comment: You can think of a schema as a user which own objects

Comment: @A.B.Cade - that thread you link contains a deleted post which links to a blog article I wrote on this topic (I didn't post that reponse).  A mod deleted it because SO disapproves of answers which are just links but I think the article is pertinent as it explains why USER and SCHEMA aren't the same thing: http://radiofreetooting.blogspot.com/2007/02/user-schema.html

Comment: @APC, Thanks for the link, it's a great post. I know they're not the same (this is why I used words like `quite`, `pretty much` and `think as` in my comments) and I'm guilty as well in *using them interchangeably* as you nicely written...

Comment: @A.B.Cade - of course I'm guilty of using the terms interchangeably myself.  Most of the time it doesn't matter but I think in this context the distinction is crucial to any proper understanding of what is happening and why.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6014.htm):

> This statement does not actually create a schema. Oracle Database
>   automatically creates a schema when you create a user

So you first need to [create a User](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8003.htm#i2065278) with the schema name

As for your query it's fine, since username list is equal to schema names unavailable

---

**UPDATE:** I can't really test it now, but should be something like this:

```
CREATE USER oe IDENTIFIED BY oePSWRD;

CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION oe
   CREATE TABLE new_product
      (color VARCHAR2(10)  PRIMARY KEY, quantity NUMBER)
   CREATE VIEW new_product_view
      AS SELECT color, quantity FROM new_product WHERE color = 'RED'
   GRANT select ON new_product_view TO scott;
```

Comment: @jWeavers, I updated my answer. I also noticed that I forgot to add the link to the `create user` documentation...

Comment: i should use `oe` account to create `oe` schema ?

Comment: @jWeavers, according to the documentation as cited by DavidAldridge - yes

Comment: So, i have one question, when I will create new user `oe`, by default, Oracle will create new schema with the same name `oe`. So, when I will try to execute above query, won't it through any exception, since same schema is already exist ?

Comment: @jWeavers, see the documentation (it's on the first line!!): `Use the CREATE SCHEMA statement to create multiple tables and views and perform multiple grants in your own schema in a single transaction`. More than that - it staes clearly: `This statement does not actually create a schema`

Comment: which means, its just creating multiple object simultaneously. isn't ?\

Comment: Right, the real "create schema" is within the "create user"

Answer (score 2):

From the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6014.htm

> The schema name must be the same as your Oracle Database username.

Do you want to find all users, or all users for which a table (for example) exists? If the latter then ...

```
select distinct
  owner
from
  dba_tables
where
  owner not in ('SYS','SYSTEM')
```

Add in other usernames that you're not interested in listing as required.