# grant create view on Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g, privileges, create-view

I use SQL*Plus for school and I use the username Scott. I cannot create views because it says:

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges;
```

I've searched and searched, but nothing seems to get it right. Any help?

Answer (score 17):

As the error states - your privileges are insufficient to create view - you will have to ask database administrator to grant you this privilege. 
If you can log in as database administrator you will have to execute statement(I can't guarantee correctness, no oracle database at hand)

```
GRANT CREATE ANY VIEW TO Scott;
```

or

```
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO Scott;
```

Comment: Well I am using it on a home computer, so does this mean I can log in as the database administrator? If so, how?

Comment: While installing Oracle database there should be a moment when you had to choose your admin password or try to log in with defalut user SYSTEM and password MANAGER.

Comment: You can try this answer for more information on how to log into Oracle db, how to grant privileges and some more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403125/how-to-create-a-new-schema-new-user-in-oracle-11g

Answer (score 1):

You need to **GRANT** the **CREATE VIEW** privilege to the **USER** which is creating the view.

For example, I create a new user to let it create a session, a table and a view:

```
SQL> create user test identified by test;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table, create view to test;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn test/test@pdborcl;
Connected.
SQL> Create Table advanced
  2   (Id  varchar(15),
  3   Name varchar(20),
  4   Dept  varchar(15),
  5   Cgpa  float,
  6   Birth_date date,
  7   Mob_no  int,
  8   Dist varchar(20),
  9   Salary  number(8));

Table created.

SQL> Create View advanced_data as
  2  (
  3  select name,dept,dist,salary from advanced
  4  );

View created.
```

If I **revoke** the privilege, you will recieve **ORA-01031: insufficient privileges**:

```
SQL> revoke create view from test;

Revoke succeeded.

SQL> conn test/test@pdborcl;
Connected.
SQL> Create or replace View advanced_data as
  2  (
  3  select name,dept,dist,salary from advanced
  4  );
Create or replace View advanced_data as
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Answer (score 0):

step 1-conn ss/ss as sysdba;
step 2- GRANT CREATE ANY VIEW TO Scott;
step 3- conn scott/tiger
step 4-create or replace   view v as select *from emp;

Answer (score -1):

To log-in as DBA (database administrator) you can use:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

or

```
sqlplus sys as sysdba
```