# Insufficient privilege error when creating view

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to create a view that is referencing to dba_objects table. 
I can select the dba_objects just fine but when I try to create a view I am getting an insuf priv error.

```
select * from session_privs //this returns create view privilege
```

```
create view v_test_view 
as 
select * from dba_objects
where owner = 'HR'

ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Comment: grant privilege by `grant select on dba_objects to <your_current_user>` from sys or system users.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595701/grant-create-view-on-oracle-11g) SO post if it helps.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allowed to select from `DBA_OBJECTS`. A privileged user (such as SYS) has to grant you `select` privilege on it.

Alternatively, if it is enough for what you're doing, select from `ALL_OBJECTS` which contains all objects you have access to.

Comment: I can select dba_objects with no issues at all.

Comment: Try to grant `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` to user which is creating the view.