# How to find primary key on a table in DB2?

Tags: db2, primary-key

I am unable to fetch primary key in DB2. I used following code but It is not working for me.

SELECT TBCREATOR, TBNAME, NAME, KEYSEQ
       FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS
       WHERE TBCREATOR = 'DSN8710'
       AND TBNAME = 'EMPLOYEE'
       AND KEYSEQ > 0
         ORDER BY KEYSEQ;

And what is the means of TBCREATOR in this code and how to modified TBCREATOR value according to my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer your last question first. `creator` is sometimes referred to as `schema`. If you're familiar with Oracle, this is [roughly analogous to a database user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880230/difference-between-a-user-and-a-schema-in-oracle) (though not exactly).

As far as getting the "primary key" information, you probably want to know which index is the ["clustering" index](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_clusteringindexes.dita) (which is what *usually*, but not always, determines the physical ordering of the rows on disk).

How you find the clustering index depends on the platform you're running:

### Mainframe (z/OS):

```
SELECT
     RTRIM(name)    AS index_name
    ,RTRIM(creator) AS index_schema
    ,uniquerule
    ,clustering
FROM sysibm.sysindexes
WHERE tbname     = @table
  AND tbcreator  = @schema
  AND clustering = 'Y'
```

Then, to see the actual columns in that index, you perform this query:

```
SELECT colname AS name
FROM sysibm.sysindexes a
JOIN sysibm.syskeys b
    ON a.name       = b.ixname 
    AND a.tbcreator = b.ixcreator 
WHERE a.name        = @index_name
    AND a.tbcreator = @index_schema
ORDER BY COLSEQ
```

### Linux/Unix/Windows:

```
SELECT
     RTRIM(indname)   AS index_name
    ,RTRIM(indschema) AS index_schema
    ,uniquerule
    ,indextype
FROM syscat.indexes
WHERE tabname     = @table
  AND tabschema = @schema
  AND indextype = 'CLUS'
```

Then, to see the actual columns in that index, you perform this query:

```
SELECT colnames as name
FROM sysibm.sysindexes
WHERE name        = @index_name
    AND tbcreator = @index_schema
ORDER BY NAME
```

LUW returns the list of columns as one string, delimited by `+`, which is kind of weird...

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong about the creator and schema. `CREATOR` is the authorization ID of the user who ran the DDL statement, nothing more. It will be equal to the schema only in one case: when the schema name is not explicitly specified and DB2 derives it from the same source -- user's authorization ID. `create table mytab`, `create table foo.mytab`, and `set schema bar; create table mytab` will all have the same creator, but different schema names.

Comment: @mustaccio: I think in the context of the catalog views, however, the view columns that include `creator` actually refer to the object's `schema` (at least on z/OS... it appears that in LUW's `SYSCAT` tables, they've renamed it to have `SCHEMA`). For example, the description for `CREATOR` in the [`SYSTABLES`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsystablestable.dita?cp=SSEPEK_10.0.0%2F10-0-111&lang=en) view says "The **schema** of the table, view, or alias." Additionally, there is a separated `CREATEDBY` column on SYSTABLES.

Comment: @mustaccio However, I do agree that if you don't provide the schema when creating the object, it is implicitly the [`CURRENT SCHEMA`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_currentschema.dita?lang=en) special register, which is your auth id by default.