# How to get user of a schema with sql/plsql

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am login with a user `abc` in a database `xyz` with **Oracle SQL Developer**. How can I get the usernames of the schema through which I am logged in?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the usernames of a schema" in Oracle. A schema and a username are essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe by *usernames* you mean operating system usernames. Username in Oracle database (and SQL Developer), is a synonym to the schema name.

So in your case, your schema called *abc*. Now assume your operating system username is 'John', and you want to know other users who are connected to the schema 'abc', then you can run the query:

```
SELECT osuser 
FROM   v$session 
WHERE  schemaname = 'abc';
```

Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880230/difference-between-a-user-and-a-schema-in-oracle) for more details

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know the list of users in the schema you are in, try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM all_users
```

Comment: This query will return the schema names/usernames of the entire database

Answer (score 0):

If you do not change current schema the following code will be fine:

```
-- In PLSQL
DECLARE
  vv_SchemaName VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  vv_SchemaName := Sys_Context('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA');
  dbms_output.put_line(vv_SchemaName);
END;  

-- IN SQL
SELECT Sys_Context('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA') FROM DUAL
```

Current_schema is a bit different from LOGGED USER see the example:

```
-- The output will be: 
-- Current schema:LOGGED_SCHEMA session user:LOGGED_SCHEMA
-- Current schema:CHANGED_SCHEMA session user:LOGGED_SCHEMA
-- When you are connected to LOGGED_SCHEMA and have CHANGED_SCHEMA.
DECLARE
  vv_SchemaName  VARCHAR2(100);
  vv_SessionUser VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  vv_SchemaName  := Sys_Context('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA');
  vv_SessionUser := Sys_Context('USERENV','SESSION_USER'  ); 
  dbms_output.put_line('Current schema:' || vv_SchemaName || ' session user:' || vv_SessionUser);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=CHANGED_SCHEMA';
  vv_SchemaName  := Sys_Context('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA');
  vv_SessionUser := Sys_Context('USERENV','SESSION_USER'  ); 
  dbms_output.put_line('Current schema:' || vv_SchemaName || ' session user:' || vv_SessionUser);  
END;
```

So If you plan to connect to one user and work on another one than depending on your needs using Sys_Context('USERENV','SESSION_USER'  ) may be a better option.