# Insert Dataset in a table in Oracle using Python

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I want to load a very large dataset into the Oracle database using Python. For Microsoft SQL, I used SQLALchemy and I was superfast. I want to use the same procedure for the Oracle as follows

```
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy
 

dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port,service_name)
 
engine = create_engine(
    f'oracle://{<username>}:{<password>}@{dsn}', max_identifier_length=128)
 
df.to_sql(table_name, engine, index=False, if_exists="replace")
```

This throws an error as follows:

```
DatabaseError: (cx_oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-01031: insufficient privileges [SQL: CREATE TABLE ....
```

Interestingly, we used the same user and load a dataset from sqlplus and it worked there but here it returns back an error.

I should mention that I can read the data from oracle like the below one:

```
pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT * FROM <TABLE_NAME>""")
```

To solve this issue I tried the following code:

```
cursor.execute("""grant insert on <table_name> to <user>""")
```

But, this one also returns the following error

```
ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself
```

Do you have any solutions? Please note that I used the same userid and loaded the data into oracle somewhere else.

Here are the privileges that are currently available for the user:

```
SELECT * FROM session_privs
```

1. CREATE SESSION
2. UNLIMITED TABLESPACE

The final solution for me:

1. use the lower case of table name (I do not why)
2. use if_exists = "append"
   Of course, it is required to truncate the records before appending, for that, I used a procedure that was already available in our oracle serve (using `cursor.callproc()`). `TRUNCATE TABLE <TABLE_NAME>` did not work.

Comment: It's better to ask required grants your DBA, if you have one

Comment: Does fast_executemany actually work with Oracle?  The sqlachemy doc mentions it for other DBs.  For reference, see the raw cx_Oracle doc [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).

Comment: `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges [SQL: CREATE TABLE` - your error states `CREATE table`, so you need `grant resource` role or `grant create table` privilege

Comment: @ChristopherJones I am not sure about that. But if I remove that I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas code appears consistent with your Oracle user privileges. In SQL*Plus, it sounds like you never had to *create* a table, only load data with `INSERT`. Likely you do not have `CREATE TABLE` privileges which is a *user* level privilege not *table* level privilege as you show. User level changes can only be granted by a DBA or power user.

Under the hood, Pandas' [`to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) can run up to three SQL commands depending on arguments as suggested by docs:

> **if_exists**: {‘fail’, ‘replace’, ‘append’}, default ‘fail’ 
>  How to behave
> if the table already exists.
>
> - **fail**: Raise a ValueError.
> - **replace**: Drop the table before inserting new values.
> - **append**: Insert new values to the existing table.

In SQL, `replace` argument which you specify will attempt to run three commands:

1. `DROP TABLE table_name`
2. `CREATE TABLE table_name (...)`
3. `INSERT INTO table_name ...`

Please note in SQL, there is no single command to replace a table, only two separate [DDL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/statements_1001.htm#i2099120) steps: `DROP` and `CREATE`.

Comment: Even, in case I use "append" I get the same error. I updated the available privileges for the user in my question. Please take a look at it and let me know your opinion.

Comment: If you have a very large dataset, then use raw cx_Oracle and skip one layer of abstraction (SQL Alchemy).  I gave a link for bulk loading earlier.

Comment: If `append` triggers the same error, table may not previously exist in that schema. In Oracle, [user = schema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/880230/1422451) unlike other RDBMSs. Also, I am not an expert on Oracle privileges but [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTSQL/privileges.htm#TTSQL339) indicate `CREATE SESSION` is a separate privilege to `CREATE TABLE`. Also, [`UNLIMITED TABLESPACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/users.htm#DBSEG10240) does not immediately indicate `CREATE TABLE` privileges. To confirm, in SQL\*Plus try `CREATE TABLE` with that user.

Comment: Per your final solution, I almost thought of that common issue in raising error with `append`. In Pandas, if you use mixed cases in table name, underlying SQL queries will add double quotes to table name which makes it case sensitive. So `"MYTABLE"` even `"MyTable"` is an entirely different table than `"mytable"`, so pandas will attempt to create the *new* unknown table and hence your same raised error.

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges [SQL: CREATE TABLE

That means that you need to connect as a `sys as sysdba` and execute `grant resource to <username>`. Do not forget also grant to tablespaces. The easiest is without quota limit:  `GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO <username>`

> ORA-01749: you may not GRANT/REVOKE privileges to/from yourself

Just use sys user to grant privileges. Don't use the same user.

Comment: But as I mentioned above when I use the same USER ID in SQLPLUS, I can insert a table into the database and there is no any issue. Why this happening?

Comment: Just enable sql_trace on your python session and check what user and DDL do you exactly run

Comment: Also try to execute `SET ROLE ALL` in your session before any DDL. Probably you just haven't set default roles

Comment: Maybe that's because SQL*Plus isn't creating a table.  What SQL statements is Pandas running?  Set the environment variable [`DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL`](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/user_guide/debugging.html) to 16 and try again.  The standard error output will log the SQL statements.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thanks! how can I set up DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov. None of them worked! When I check the privileges >> select_priv is Y, insert_priv is A, delete_priv is Y, update_priv is A, alter_priv is N. Is this helpful?

Comment: @Naik None of what? How do you check privileges? Your error shows error on `create table`, not update or insert. If you want to check current session's privileges you need to run `select * from session_privs` in your python app. Also you still haven't showed exact sql you are trying to run. We don't even know in shich schema are you trying to create table. If you are trying to create table in another schema (ie different from your username), then you need to grant role `resource` and `unlimited tablespace` to that user too

Comment: and in addition in this case you need `grant create ANY table` to the user that you are using to connect

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov. You proposed two suggestions in the comments above. I meant none of them worked. This user has tablespace but not resource privilege. I will check that one. Also, I should mention that there is a table in my database and I want to replace that one. I do not want to create a new one.

Comment: @Naik please enable sql_trace and post raw trace file here, so we could know what exactly ran and return

Comment: I get the ORA-01031 for even for enabling sql_trace!

Comment: DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL is an environment variable - how you set it will depend on how and where you are invoking the program. If you are on Linux (or macOS bash shell), use something like `export DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL=16`.  On Windows something like `set DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL=16` in the terminal that you are running your program in, or in the system settings pane.